# Get range of elements from array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var year = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];

var monthsRange = ["aug", "oct"];
```

I need to get an array having all the months between 'aug' and 'oct' and these two also based on year array.

Expected output: `var newArr = ["aug", "sept", "oct"];`

If `var monthsRange = ["aug", "sept"];` then Expected output: `var newArr = ["aug", "sept"];`

If `var monthsRange = ["aug"];` then Expected output: `var newArr = ["aug"];`

Comment: what about `["oct", "aug"]`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

```
year.slice(year.indexOf(monthsRange[0]), year.indexOf(monthsRange[1]) + 1)
```

```js
var year = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];

var monthsRange = ["aug", "oct"];

function getMonths(r, y) {
  return r.length > 1 ? y.slice(y.indexOf(r[0]), y.indexOf(r[1]) + 1) : r;
}

console.log(getMonths(monthsRange, year));
console.log(getMonths(["aug"], year));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following way? If you want to try a little different way.

```js
var year = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];

var monthsRange = ["aug", "oct"];

function checkMonth(month) {
    return year.indexOf(month) >= year.indexOf(monthsRange[0]) && year.indexOf(month) <= year.indexOf(monthsRange[1]);
}

console.log(year.filter(checkMonth));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thisp proposal works for `monthsRange = ["sep", "feb"]` as well.

```js
function getMonths(range) {
    var year = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
        start = year.indexOf(range[0]),
        end = year.indexOf(range[1] || range[0]);

    if (start <= end) {
        return year.slice(start, end + 1);
    } else {
        return year.slice(start).concat(year.slice(0, end + 1));
    }
}

console.log(getMonths(["sep", "feb"]));
console.log(getMonths(["mar"]));
console.log(getMonths(["may", "oct"]));
```